# In extnjs for a dropdown list,object is not getting selected and clicked

Tags: extjs, selenium-webdriver

Am trying to select a data from a dropdown which is already having a preselected value "Y", object is getting clicked but the values from the dropdown is not getting selected getting this

TimeoutException:Times out after 40 sec waiting for visibility of element located by By.xpath://li[contains(text(),'N')]

code:

```
action.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='flag']"))).click().perform();

Wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//li[contains(text(),'Y')]")));

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[contains(text(),'Y')]")).click();


    html code:
       <div>
      <input id="combobox-233-inputE1" class="x-form-field x-form-text" 
      type="text" autocomplete="off" readonly="readonly" value="Y"
       name="FlagName"  size="2" role="combobox" data-ref="inputE1" 
       componentid="combobox-233"></div>


        <div><ul>
   <li class=somename" unselectedable="on" role="option" tabindex="0">Y   </li>
   <li class=somename" unselectedable="on" role="option" tabindex="-1" >N   </li>
   </ul></div>
```

Comment: Are you sure your `xpath` is correct?? could you share your HTML as well..

Comment: Yes 1lines works fine ., it's gets clicked at the dropdown   And xpath of 2nd is right

Comment: Share your HTML for this..

Comment: @SaurabhGaur added the corresponding html code.Please ref

Comment: Ok try provided answer and let me know...:)

Answer (score 0):

You should try as below :-

```
action.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.name("flag"))).click().perform();

WebElement el = Wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("li[tabindex = '0']")));

el.click();
```